# Smooth animation on QStackedWidget

Tags: qt, animation

i have five Qwidgets (Each QWidget having different controls). i put all the QWidget into one Parent QStackedWidget. for change the display of Qwidget i am using setCurrentIndex(int) function.

There is no problem in displaying. but i need to put animation while changing the page.

i tried nothing is working. so i removed the QStackedWidget and i put QWidget directly and i tried with QPropertyAnimation.

This QPropertyAnimation is working but it's not the smooth animation. Here my code for QPropertyAnimation.

```
QRect pGeo(8,152,width()-16,height()-160);
profilePage->show(); //first QWidget 
QPropertyAnimation *anim1= new QPropertyAnimation(profilePage, "geometry");
anim1->setStartValue(QRect(200,pGeo.y(),pGeo.width(),pGeo.height()));
anim1->setEndValue(pGeo);
anim1->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::InOutSine);
anim1->setDuration(500);
anim1->start();
```

how to do the smooth animation using the QWidget or the QStackedWidget. Please give some suggestion to implement the smooth animation.

Comment: Which platform? Desktop? Mobile?

Comment: Does your CPU usage spike up during the animation?

Answer (score 0):

Try placing on `QGraphicsWidget`. it might work